# Phonegap + onsoftKeyboard adjusting pan

Tags: cordova, screen

I'm developing a phonegap application,i'm facing a problem when the virtual keyboard appears when entering the values for the fields, the fields are getting hide when the virtual keyboard appears.

i have added following code:
at html page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

at activity oncreate:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

at android manifest file :

```
<activity
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible|adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:name="com.newgen.omniflowmobile.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dealt with the same issue using Cordova 3.0 + JQM 1.3.2 and there seems to be a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4404) with android:windowSoftInputMode and a fullscreen webview. One thing that should fix the issue of the keyboard covering input fields is setting "fullscreen" to false in config.xml:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

I'm now dealing with the keyboard pushing content up...bottom admob banner, text covering header, etc.